# Number of different solutions of xy+yz+ xz = N

Tags: number-theory

I have been trying to solve a problem on spoj.
Here is the link to the problem.

http://www.spoj.pl/problems/TAP2012B/

From what I have interpreted, I need to find the number of solutions of the equation xy+yz+xz = N
where n is given to us.
x>=y>=z
z can be zero.
But x and y cannot.
I tried doing solving this via implementing 3 for loops (bad approach).
It is giving the right answer but it is too slow.
Also, other people have solved it in almost no time (0.00)
So I am sure there is a very different approach to this problem.
For N = 20,
the number of different solutions is 5 :
(6,2,1)
(5,4,0)
(10,2,0)
(4,2,2,)
(20,1,0)

Comment: On my machine, it runs 5 seconds for N=10000. It is python implementation. Is it slow or O.K?

Comment: My example runs 0.12 s. for 9747 and I still think it has optimizational potential.

Comment: Very well! +1 on your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there is some brillian solution built on number-theory. But simply rethinking the task can reduce algorithm complexity as well.

For instance, we don't need a third loop as we can calculate `z` as `(N - x*y)/(x+y)`. And we don't have to run `y` all the way to `x` every time, as we know, that `z` is not negative, therefore `N >= xy`.

```
N = 9747
for x in range(1, N+1):
    max_y = min( N / x, x) 
    for y in range(1, max_y+1):
        if (N - x*y) % (x+y) == 0:
            z = (N - x*y) / (x+y)
            if z <= y:
                print x,y,z
```

Answer (score 1):

You are approaching towards the right direction there will be 3 nested loops but try to reduce the no. of times the loop operates.... Follow the question and conditions carefully.....

Answer (score 0):

You are obviously learning, so it would have had been better if you would do everything yourself, but you now have a great solution from akalenuk, and I hope that you will learn a few things from it as well.

If you are learning python at the same time, I will give you an equivalent solution to akalenuk's, but this time with list comprehension which is a very useful mechanism:

```
N = 10000

print [(x, y, z)
       for x in range(1, N+1)
       for y in range(1, min( N/x, x) + 1 )
       for z in [ (N - x*y) / (x+y) ] 
       if (N - x*y) % (x+y) == 0
       if z <= y]
```

The point is in pruning the solution space. The code above is already quite optimised. You might start with something like:

```
N = 10000

print [(x, y, z)
       for x in range(1, N+1)
       for y in range(1, x+1 )
       for z in range(y+1) 
       if N == x*y + y*z + x*z]
```

This would run quite long. So, the first point of optimization may be adding the condition on y:

```
N = 10000

print [(x, y, z)
       for x in range(1, N+1)
       for y in range(1, x+1 )
       if x*y <= N
       for z in range(y+1) 
       if N == x*y + y*z + x*z]
```

This already cuts down the time considerably, as for non-promising `y` the `z`-loop is not run at all. Then, you notice that you may actually replace that if-statement by explicit computation of maximum y, as akalenuk did:

```
N = 10000

print [(x, y, z)
       for x in range(1, N+1)
       for y in range(1, min(x, N/x) +1)
       for z in range(y+1) 
       if N == x*y + y*z + x*z]
```

This will again speed it up.

As you are learning, I recommend you try all these, and your own, time it, and learn from it.
I also recommend to try and time different, similar solutions